# magento listing all bundled product made using specific product id

Tags: catalog, bundled-product

i had make few bundled product which is bacially group of two products.

now i want to get list of all product id that have other product in bundle.

Suppose i made bundled product using (1,2) ,(1,4) ,(3,2), (1,6)

by id 1 i want to get product ids: 2,4,6

how can i do it

Answer (score 1):

1. find all bundle selections for your product

   ```
   $selectionsForReferenceProduct = Mage::getResourceModel('bundle/selection_collection')
           ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $productId);
   ```
2. for each of them, get the option id

   ```
   $optionId = $selection->getOptionId();
   ```
3. find all other bundle selections associated to these options

   ```
   $selectionsForAssociatedProducts = Mage::getResourceModel('bundle/selection_collection')->setOptionIdsFilter($optionIds)
   ```
4. for each of them, get the product id

   ```
   $productId = $selection->getId();
   ```

Note that `Mage_Bundle_Model_Resource_Selection_Collection` extends `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection` and joins the selection table, this is why the collection items are instances of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` with additional data from the selection table and you get the product id with `getId()`